# Which software/setting do I need to get my first "Hello World" in Struts?

Tags: struts2

I'd like to learn Struts 2. Unlike when I learned **ASP.NET MVC/C#** where I needed just to download VS2008 Express sp1 (Server Casini, Linq where included), I downloaded **Eclipse Gallileo**, but it looks like it's not enough. I'd like to know what (and how) to set up my machine environment so that I can write my first **Hello world** in Struts.

I've checked the Apache Struts web page, but I didn't really understand. Maybe because I was expecting Microsoft-like packages.

So,

- Which software do I need (beside Eclipse)
- How to set them up

Thanks for helping

Comment: here's an example http://javachamp.blogspot.com/2008/07/struts-2-hello-world-example.html

Comment: @Josek: It looks nice to me. But, I've just one concern. The blog you pointed me to has been written on July 7th 2008. Things are still done the same way? If so, that's fine with me. I just need confirmation.

Comment: Beware: don't confuse "Struts" with "Struts2", it's not a mere version number, they are radically different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apache struts2 website and download struts-2.2.1-apps.zip it contains 4 sample application war file put the .war file in to Tomcat webapp and restrt the server you can see these application running

else deploy these war in to tomcat using its Admin pannel from there you can see the application running